# "Catching" query from oracle forms

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I would like to know if it is possible and how to "catch" query
or WHERE part of SELECT after i enter value and press F8 to excecute query,
is it possible to catch that query and how.

tnx

Answer (score 1):

Use `get_block_property` built-in. One of its parameters is `last_query` which

> Returns the SQL statement of the last query in the specified block

Also, have a look at `default_where` and `onetime_where` parameters.

For more info, see Online Forms Help system (now that you know what to search for).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a POST-QUERY trigger and in it add code similar to the following:

```
DECLARE
   lastSuccessfulQuery varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   lastSuccessfulQuery := :SYSTEM.LAST_QUERY;
   --
   -- Do something with the value here
   --
END;
```